Laravel 11 Artisan lang:publish generates empty lang folder
Following the documentation, I tried to run php artisan lang:publish but it generates an empty lang folder. I would expect there will be at least messages.php file for English. Can somebody tell me why it is empty? I run the command in docker terminal but it is empty in docker container and also in computer disk.


The command was introduced in laravel/framework PR #45902 without further modifications. Is there no new entry in the error log after running the command?

No there was not error. The command returned success. But I tried it again and now everything is ok. I dont understand.

If, for some reason, it couldn't write to the hard drive (permissions, storage, corrupted sector, etc.), then I think you should have received an error message. The code I referred to is quite simple and should work as expected. Since it ran perfectly the second time, the situation is a bit questionable; maybe it was interrupted the first time (for example, you stopped it in the terminal, so you didn't get an error, but the result didn't come out either). In any case, I'm glad it worked the second time.

Seems like you have some problems with the mount synchronization between your Docker volume and your file system.
Try to run the command either inside the Docker container (docker compose exec <app_name> php artisan lang:publish) and outside it (just plain php artisan lang:publish) and see what happens.
Anyway, its better to provide some additional context in such questions. Like run command, it’s output, and contents of storage/logs/laravel.log (maybe it contains some exceptions).

There was no error. Command returned success but lang direcotry was empty. Today I tried it againg and now it worked properly. I dont understand.

do you have write permission to the lang folder?
also, please check if the
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Translation/lang
has content in it.
not a solution but a workaround: you can actually manually copy files from
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Translation/lang
to your
resources/lang
folder.
